# $scope in controller is not accessible in view / data binding not working (IONIC/ANGULAR)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

In my controller:

```
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, lodash) {

$scope.selectedContact = lodash.findWhere($scope.businesscards, { Id: parseInt($stateParams.contactId) });

console.log($scope.selectedContact);
 });
```

In my View:

```
<div class="item">
{{ $scope.selectedContact }}
<h2>{{ $scope.selectedContact.Full_Name }}</h2>
<p>{{ $scope.selectedContact.Company | uppercase }}</p>
</div>
```

Why I cannot access **$scope.selectedContact** and even **$stateParams.contactId** in my view?

Comment: `$scope` is implicit in expressions `{{ }}` and should not be provided.  try `{{selectedContact}}`.

Comment: use {{selectedContact }} instead of{{ $scope.selectedContact }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$scope is the connector between the controller and view. In your case you are defining "selectedContact" variable with $scope when you need to print in controller then you need to do like this ( $scope.selectedContact ) or in view you can simple do {{selectedContact}}

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{ var }}` to access `$scope.var` in your view.